# Localhost works, github-pages doesnt

Tags: javascript, css, github, localhost, github-pages

My project shows correctly on localhost (html, css, js files work), but on github-pages I see only html. Can somebody help me?
This is my repo: https://github.com/agata-zybula/grupa-6-filmoteka
thanks

I tried change homepage, repository url in package.json, I tried change source of css files, removed deploy.yml and added again but it doesn't work.

Comment: Try preventing Jekyll from interfering by creating an empty `.nojekyll` file in the root directory of your site (`src`, I believe).

Comment: Thank you for answer.
Unfortunately it doesn't work, changed nothing :(

Comment: It looks like you're using a workflow with an action that's seriously outdated (over one year old), try using the most recent version (v4.4.2)

Comment: It seems like your paths are wrong. They end up requesting assets like `https://agata-zybula.github.io/grupa-6-filmoteka/grupa-6-filmoteka/library.ea7e8019.js` whereas it should be `https://agata-zybula.github.io/grupa-6-filmoteka/library.ea7e8019.js` This is because the paths are relative `src="grupa-6-filmoteka/library.ea7e8019.js"` which means they get "added" on to the current URL. You could look at using root-relative URLs like  `src="/grupa-6-filmoteka/library.ea7e8019.js"` or changing the URLs to `src="library.ea7e8019.js"`, etc.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

The name of the other .scss extension files you imported in the main.scss file does not match.  This may be the problem.